# Bash Script Calls another bash script and waits for it to complete before proceeding

Tags: bash

I have 1 bash script that runs another bash script, however the first bashscript isn't waiting for the second one to complete before proceeding, how can I force it to wait?

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# first.sh

#call to secondary script
sh second.sh
echo "second.sh has completed"

echo "continuing with the rest of first.sh..."
```

The way it is now, it will run second.sh, and continue on, without waiting for second.sh to complete.

Comment: It should be waiting; is that really your whole script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normally it does; something else is happening. Are you sure that the other script isn't running something in the background instead? You can try using `wait` regardless.

Comment: 'wait' only waits for direct children of the parent bash; if the child runs something in the background and exits, the parent process cannot wait for it because it is inherited by 'PID 1' - the init process.  (Unless something has changed dramatically that I don't know about.)

Comment: Is there a way to wait regardless? Can't I just wait in the called script and also in  the calling script?

Answer (score 28):

AS  I use scheme like this in few scripts - just calling second scripts in the same shell-copy using `source`.

In `script-1`:

```
source script2.sh
```

or:

```
. script2.sh
```

So - no one command in `script-1` will not be proceeded till `script2.sh` will end all it's tasks.

Little example.

First script:

```
$ cat script-1.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm sccript $0."
echo "Runnig script-2..."

source script-2.sh

echo "script-2.sh finished!"
```

Second script:

```
$ cat script-2.sh
#bin/bash
echo "I'm script-2. Running wait operation..."
sleep 2
echo "I'm ended my task."
```

How it works:

```
$ ./script-1.sh
I'm sccript ./script-1.sh.
Runnig script-2...
I'm script-2. Running wait operation...
I'm ended my task.
script-2.sh finished!
```

Comment: what if script-2.sh fails. Then will it call the last echo command or just exits ?

Comment: @etl_devs I think it will just exit with an error and will interrupt script-1.

Comment: What if script-2 takes arguments. How to source then.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply add the command `wait` after you execute the second script, it will wait for all process that you launch from your principal script

You can even recuperate the PID of your second script using the command `echo $!` directly after you call the second script, and then pass this PID as an argument to the `wait` command

Answer (score 1):

try using `bash second.sh` and check your second.sh and make sure you don't have programs that run in the background

Answer (score -2):

Another way to do it `$(second.sh)`

Comment: That will attempt to run the output of `second.sh` as a command. What if it prints `rm -rf *`?